# Is there a difference between the "configurable" and installable memory limit?

Tags: imac, memory

On [Apple's iMac page](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/imac/select), it says:

> Configurable to 8GB (all models) or 16GB (select models)

However both Apple's [iMac: How to remove or install memory](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1423#1) page and Crucial.com indicate that *all* of the 2011 iMac models are configurable to 16 GB. Does the above quote simply mean than select models are only configurable to 16 GB *on the Apple online store*? If I buy the $1200 iMac (MC309LL/A), I should be able to install 16 GB of RAM bought separately from Crucial, correct?

Comment: What's ever worse is that the manuals for the iMacs say (incorrectly) that they all have 4 RAM slots. In fact, the model you mention has only two slots on the logic board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. You may even [upgrade it to 32GB](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/stats/imac-core-i5-2.5-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2011-thunderbolt-specs.html).

Comment: The iMac MC309LL/A has only two RAM slots. I know of no reputable vendor that has said a pair of 16 GB RAM will work to take that model to 32 GB. Have you actually tried a chip of that sizing? A pair of 8 works well as we tested some today on that exact model.

Comment: Why do so many sites (even Apple's own support page) claim it supports 16 GB and that it has 4 slots - have you personally seen that the latest MC309LL/A has only 2 memory slots?

Answer (score 0):

Apple offers CTO and will let you fill your iMac (Late 2011) with RAM modules sized at 2 GB and 4 GB each.

From Apple, the entry level MC309LL/A has two RAM slots so you can take it to **8 GB** *(2 x 4 GB SO-DIMM)* but many reputable vendors are selling 8 GB modules that seem to work well and without issue on that hardware - **16 GB** *(2 x 8 GB SO-DIMM)*.

The rest of the Late 2011 iMacs have 4 RAM slots, so you can take them to **32 GB** *(4 x 8 GB SO-DIMM)* even though Apple intends / configures / supports / recommends a max of **16 GB** *(4 x 4 GB SO-DIMM)* for the rest of the lineup.

Comment: 21.5" always had 4 slots
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzZ9nRJz7AQ
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGdW9cbZF0Y
http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac-Intel-21-5-Inch-EMC-2428-Teardown/5485/1

Comment: Just a nitpick, but computers in general (including Macs) do **not** take ram *"Chips"*, they take RAM *modules*, or (colloquially) *sticks*. The RAM module has chips *on it*, but calling the whole thing a *chip* is akin to referring to an entire car as an engine or tire.